# Flutter avoid widget rebuild on collapsing/expanding ExpansionPanelList

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management

In `ExpansionPanelList`, I have a problem of rebuilding widget when I expand/collapse it.

The problem is here:

```
expansionCallback: (int index, bool isExpanded) {
  setState(() {
    _profileExpansionStateMap[_profileExpansionStateMap.keys.toList()[index]] = !isExpanded;
  });
},
```

I changed it to use `Bloc` state management to solve, but that has same behavior with `setState()`. Is there any way to avoid rebuilding widget tree? I can't use `Selector` widget as I don't think it would help me here.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main()=>runApp(MaterialApp(home: Home(),));

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() =>HomeState();

}

class HomeState extends State<Home> {
  Map<String, bool> _profileExpansionStateMap = Map<String, bool>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _profileExpansionStateMap = {
      "UserInformation": false,
      "UserWeight": false,
      "UserGeneralInformation": false,
    };
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title:Text('ExpansionPanel')),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child:ExpansionPanelList(
            expansionCallback: (int index, bool isExpanded) {
              setState(() {
                _profileExpansionStateMap[_profileExpansionStateMap.keys.toList()[index]] = !isExpanded;
              });
            },
            children: <ExpansionPanel>[
              ExpansionPanel(
                  headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
                    return Container(
                      height: 80.0,
                      child: Text('aaaaaaaa'),
                    );
                  },
                  body: Container(child:Text('aaaaaaaa')),
                  isExpanded: _profileExpansionStateMap["UserInformation"]),
              ExpansionPanel(
                  headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
                    return Container(
                      height: 80.0,
                      child: Text('bbbbbbbbbbbb'),
                    );
                  },
                  body: Container(child:Text('bbbbbbbbbbbb')),
                  isExpanded: _profileExpansionStateMap["UserWeight"]),
              ExpansionPanel(
                  headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
                    return Container(
                      height: 80.0,
                      child: Text('ccccccccc'),
                    );
                  },
                  body: Container(child:Text('ccccccccc')),
                  isExpanded: _profileExpansionStateMap["UserGeneralInformation"]),
            ],
          )
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ExpansionPanelList.expansionCallback(...)` is a method that gets called whenever you tap on arrow buttons inside your `ExpansionPanelList` to expand/collapse it.

In this method you are actually supposed to setup your `bool` values passed to `isExpanded` of `ExpansionPanel` thus requiring you to call `setState(...)`.

If you, however, have issues with this, then it clearly indicates there is something wrong with your code. So, there is no need to avoid rebuilding the widget state.

Comment: I think you are right, I'll try to change my implementation, thanks